# Trying to get property of non-object (View:

Tags: php, laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

test blade.php

```
@foreach($preguntas as $pregunta)
    <td>{{$pregunta->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$pregunta->Pregunta}}</td>
    <td>{{$pregunta->Opcion1}}</td>
    <td>{{$pregunta->Opcion2}}</td>
    <td>{{$pregunta->Opcion3}}</td>
    <td>{{$pregunta->Opcion4}}</td>
    <td>{{$pregunta->Respuesta}}</td>
    <td>{{$pregunta->cargo_id}}</td>
    <td>
@endforeach
```

controlador

```
public function show(Preguntas $preguntas)
{

    return view('preguntas.test', compact('preguntas'));
}
```

rutas

```
Route::get('/preguntas/test/{preguntas}', 'PreguntasController@test');
```

la verdad es que no se donde esta el error si necesitan mas codigo puedo mandar

Comment: si solo 1 el id la pregunta las posibles respuestas y el cargo ya arregle lo de los join ahora necesito eso para poder desplegar el quiz con los datos de la bd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Dentro de tu método `show` planeas mostrar las propiedades de un registro por lo tanto no estás obteniendo una **Collection**
- Solamente tienes como retorno un registro con una estructura similar a esta:

Código:

```
=> App\Modelo {#3039
     id: 1,
     name: "valor1",
     descripcion: "",
     created_at: "2020-03-31 13:22:19",
     updated_at: "2020-03-31 13:22:19",
   }
>>>
```

Dado lo anterior no puedes iterar, basta con acceder directamente a las propiedades del resultado así: **`$preguntas->propiedad`**

Entonces en tu vista deberías tener algo así:

```
<td>{{$preguntas->id}}</td>
<td>{{$preguntas->Pregunta}}</td>
<td>{{$preguntas->Opcion1}}</td>
<td>{{$preguntas->Opcion2}}</td>
<td>{{$preguntas->Opcion3}}</td>
<td>{{$preguntas->Opcion4}}</td>
<td>{{$preguntas->Respuesta}}</td>
<td>{{$preguntas->cargo_id}}</td>
```

Comment: me funciono con la s muchas gracias